# So if a a Singelton calls a method that throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, singleton

So this is a follow-up to a previous question that I asked: [Trying to figure out if this code creates any benefit by using a Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793453/trying-to-figure-out-if-this-code-creates-any-benefit-by-using-a-singleton)

In a nutshell, I have inherited a poorly architected program that uses a pseudo-facade class and places it into a Singelton. Every method call goes through the Singleton which then calls different methods.

The Singelton looks like this:

```
public class FooFacade
{
    private static FooFacade m_facade = null;
    private static DataAccessManager m_dataAccessMgr = null;

    public StringBuilder Status {get; set; }

    private FooFacade()
    {
        this.Status = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public static FooFacade getInstance()
    {
        if (m_facade == null)
        {
            m_dataAccessMgr = DataAccessManager.getInstance();
            m_facade = new FooFacade();
        }

        return m_facade;
    }

    public void clearStatus()
    {
        this.Status.Remove(0, Status.Length);
    }

    public void Method1(string value1, int value2)
    {
        // do something
    }


    public int Method2(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return externalMethod(value1, value2)
    }
}
```

So in this example above, would there be a security concern if the externalMethod that is being called in Method2 threw an error?

For example:

```
public int externalMethod(value1, value2)
{
    try
    {
        return value1/value2;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

In this method, should I be concerned that a Singleton could display a thrown error to the wrong user?

When I have the chance to refactor, I'm getting rid of the Singleton, but in the meantime, I just don't want to accidentally add a huge security hole by adding better exception handling.

-Chad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that the exception thrown is displayed to another "user". The exception is thrown in the call stack of the current call, so if two different threads were to call `Method2` and in thread A the external method throws an exception and in thread B it doesn't, than only thread A would receive the exception.

Comment: Thanks. That is great to hear. Right now the code uses the Status to pass messages, which is not secure at all. So I wanted to just throw an exception and have it handled by the method that called the singleton!